# PointCloud2 for laser_geometry

Tags: ros, laser-geometry, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a code snippet from  [laser_geometry](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_geometry) tutorial. I've tried to use this code using PointCloud type (instead of PointCloud2), but it doesn't work.

```
laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;
tf::TransformListener listener_;

void scanCallback (const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan_in)
{
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud cloud;
  projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("base_link",*scan_in,cloud,listener_);

  // Do something with cloud.
}
```

How does the signature of the line,

```
projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("base_link",*scan_in,cloud,listener_);
```

look like if I would use it with PointCloud2 data type?

Another question, what is the benefit of using PointCloud2 as opposed to PointCloud?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12483/pointcloud2-for-laser_geometry/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`PointCloud2` is the "official" point cloud used by PCL. There is a direct mapping from sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 to `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` using the pcl::fromROSMsg and pcl::toROSMsg functions. I believe that PointCloud is scheduled to be phased out and replaced by PointCloud2.

The reason that you would want to use the `toROSMsg` or `fromROSMsg` calls would be to make use of PCL's built-in functions found [here](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/). For example, the `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ`> type allows you to add two point clouds together. When I do heavy Point Cloud work, I wait for a sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 callback, convert it to `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`, and then do all of my processing on that datatype, just because I like to use PCL functions.

In your above code, to use PointCloud2, all you need to change is the following line:

From:

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud cloud;
```

To:

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
```

And *viola*! It works.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-29**:
Thanks a lot for the clear explanation.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-29**:
I got your fix that i just need to change the data type from sensor_msgs::PointCloud to sensor_msgs::PointCloud2, however, when should I use  pcl::fromROSMsg and pcl::toROSMsg function calls? Is it implicitly done for us?